# MySQL database contains malicious SCRIPT tag after injection attack?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-injection, code-injection

My website was hacked with by an attacker a few weeks ago. I thought deleting is account would fix things but every time a member creates a new account, the following code appears around fields in my 'users' database that contain email information. Please help me fix this. My members information is at stake. Sorry, because of the severity of the situation I cannot provide my website for security reasons.

Here is the code that appears in the database:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
(function(){try{var s,a,i,j,r,c,l,b=document.getElementsByTagName("script");l=b[b.length-1].previousSibling;a=l.getAttribute('data-cfemail');if(a){s='';r=parseInt(a.substr(0,2),16);for(j=2;a.length-j;j+=2){c=parseInt(a.substr(j,2),16)^r;s+=String.fromCharCode(c);}s=document.createTextNode(s);l.parentNode.replaceChild(s,l);}}catch(e){}})();
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The only way to be sure is to pave your server. Start over. Hope you have backups.

Comment: I will consider this as an option but I have a theory the attacker caused SQL to perform a STORED ROUTINE in which it injects the code upon new members. I have already improved the security of my site's script using XSS filtering and PHP's strip_tags function with CodeIgniter. I mean't to add this when I launched the site but I didn't think someone would try to hack it in the 1st 24 hours. If I can delete the STORED ROUTINE then I should be fine. If not then I will take your advice. Thank you Greg.

Comment: It may also be a TRIGGER, EVENT, or all of the above.

Answer (score 0):

It's possibly not MySQL but your PHP code has been modified.

I think you can use mysqldump to get full database script including stored procedures, functions, triggers and so on and then manually check out if everything is correct.